# Table Spool right before insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-execution-plan, spool, sql-tuning

What I understand about SPOOL is to store data into a temporary table so SQL Server could use it when have CTE or other usage. Does that means SPOOL should appear in the middle of my execution plan?

- With the query below(I put SELECT * here to make the query smaller), the SPOOL shows up between INSERT and CONCATENATION actions in my execution plan. Just wondering what does this SPOOL do? Cause it costs about 30% in my execution plan. Wondering if I can make the plan get rid of it.

Edit: [Execution Plan uploaded](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8UZ7sUC_08bRjk1Z1Q1aE5FVG8)

```
    WITH FXSPOT AS (
        SELECT
              CURRENCY1
            , FXRATE
        FROM
            #DBNAME#.DBO.#TBL1#
        WHERE
            FXSPOT.DATA_DATE = '2016-10-01'
    ), FTP_MTD_PRE AS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM #DBNAME#.DBO.#TBL2#
        WHERE
            RP_DATA_DT = DATEADD(D, -1, CONVERT(DATE, '2016-10-01')) AND
            DAY(DATEADD(D, 1, CONVERT(DATE, RP_DATA_DT))) > 1 AND
            RUN_ID = 'RC01'
    ), PORT AS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM #DBNAME#.DBO.#TBL3#
    ), LK_ALL AS (
        SELECT
              FIELDNAME
            , CD
            , DESCRIPTION
        FROM #DBNAME#.DBO.#TBL4#
    ), FTP_OUT AS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM #DBNAME#.DBO.#TBL5#
        WHERE
            CURR_DT = '2016-10-01' AND
            RUN_ID = 'RC01'
    ), DEFAULT_INDEX AS (
        SELECT
            IDX_FORMULA
        FROM #DBNAME#.DBO.#TBL6#
        WHERE
            INDEX_ID = 'DEFAULT'
    ), STEP1 AS (
        SELECT
              'RC01' RUN_ID
            , CONVERT(DATE, '2016-10-01') CURRENT_DT
            , CONVERT(DATE, '2016-10-01') RP_DATA_DT
            , CASE WHEN FTP_OUT.TXN_ID IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END ERR_FLG
            , PORT.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD
            , PORT.TXN_ID
            , PORT.SCURITY_ID
            , PORT.PRODUCT_ID
            , PORT.AMRT_TYP
            , PORT.CUR_PMT
            , PORT.CURRENCY
            , PORT.DAY_COUNT
            , PORT.FIX_FLT
            , PORT.FSTAMRT_DT
            , PORT.FST_CPN_DT
            , PORT.ISSUE_DT
            , PORT.MAT_DT
            , PORT.NXT_RSTDT
            , PORT.ORG_PAR_BAL
            , PORT.ORG_PAR_BL2
            , PORT.PAY_DAY
            , PORT.PMT_FLG
            , PORT.PMT_FREQ
            , PORT.PMT_FREQ_M
            , PORT.PRV_RSTDT
            , PORT.RST_FRQ
            , PORT.RST_FRQ_M
            , PORT.SNK_DAY
            , PORT.SNK_PMT
            , PORT.SNK_RT
            , PORT.SNK_FRQ
            , PORT.SNK_FRQ_M
            , PORT.SNK_P_FLG
            , PORT.TENOR
            , PORT.TENOR_M
            , PORT.TP_ADJ1_ID
            , PORT.TP_ADJ2_ID
            , PORT.TP_ADJ3_ID
            , PORT.TP_ADJ4_ID
            , PORT.TP_ADJ5_ID
            , PORT.TP_ID
            , PORT.TP_INDEX_ID
            , PORT.TRANSPRICE
            , PORT.ASST_LIAB
            , PORT.PAR_BAL
            , PORT.CUR_BK_BAL
            , PORT.CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
            , PORT.CUR_GRS_RT
            , PORT.T_UNEARN
            , PORT.T_UNEARN * FXSPOT.FXRATE T_UNEARN_DOM
            , PORT.T_CURBAL
            , PORT.T_CURBAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE T_CURBAL_DOM
            , PORT.T_POINTAMT
            , PORT.T_POINTAMT * FXSPOT.FXRATE T_POINTAMT_DOM
            , PORT.T_RESTBALC
            , PORT.T_RESTBALC * FXSPOT.FXRATE T_RESTBALC_DOM
            , PORT.G_BANKNO
            , PORT.G_CSTCTR
            , PORT.G_GLACCTNO
            , PORT.G_GLACCTYP
            , PORT.G_GLACCTINT
            , PORT.T_RTTYP
            , PORT.T_PMTTYP
            , PORT.T_NIDPMMD
            , PORT.T_CAHSSS
            , PORT.R_LOBCD
            , PORT.R_BRNCHCD
            , PORT.R_PRODCD
            , PORT.R_TYPCD
            , PORT.R_HPTYPCD
            , PORT.R_NAME R_NAME
            , PORT.R_CUSTCODE R_CUSTCODE
            , PORT.R_PRODTYP R_PRODTYP
            , PORT.R_INTPLAN R_INTPLAN
            , PORT.R_DEPGRP_NAME R_DEPGRP_NAME
            , PORT.R_DEPID R_DEPID
            , PORT.R_MISC_IND R_MISC_IND
            , PORT.R_SRCTBL R_SRCTBL
            , PORT.R_RESTIND R_RESTIND
            , PORT.R_SECNO R_SECNO
            , PORT.R_PAIDIND R_PAIDIND
            , COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_ORIGNAL, DEFAULT_INDEX.IDX_FORMULA) TP_ORIGNAL
            , FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ1 TP_ADJ1
            , FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ2 TP_ADJ2
            , FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ3 TP_ADJ3
            , FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ4 TP_ADJ4
            , FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ5 TP_ADJ5
            , COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_FINAL, DEFAULT_INDEX.IDX_FORMULA) TP_FINAL
            , FTP_OUT.DURATION DURATION
            , FTP_OUT.WAL WAL
            , FTP_OUT.USER_INPUT USER_INPUT
            , COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_MODEL, 'D') TP_MODEL
            , FTP_OUT.TP_CLASS TP_CLASS
            , FTP_OUT.YC_DT YC_DT
            , FTP_OUT.START_DT START_DT
            , FTP_OUT.END_DT END_DT
            , (PORT.CUR_GRS_RT - COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_FINAL, DEFAULT_INDEX.IDX_FORMULA)) * PORT.ASST_LIAB TR_FINAL_SPREAD
            , (PORT.CUR_GRS_RT - COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_ORIGNAL, DEFAULT_INDEX.IDX_FORMULA)) * PORT.ASST_LIAB TR_SPREAD
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * PORT.CUR_GRS_RT / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB TR_IE_INT
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ1 / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB * -1 TR_IE_TP_ADJ1
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ2 / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB * -1 TR_IE_TP_ADJ2
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ3 / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB * -1 TR_IE_TP_ADJ3
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ4 / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB * -1 TR_IE_TP_ADJ4
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * FTP_OUT.TP_ADJ5 / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB * -1 TR_IE_TP_ADJ5
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_ORIGNAL, DEFAULT_INDEX.IDX_FORMULA) / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB * -1 TR_IE_TP_ORG
            , PORT.T_CUR_BK_BAL * FXSPOT.FXRATE * COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_FINAL, DEFAULT_INDEX.IDX_FORMULA) / 100.0 * PORT.DAY_COUNT_VALUE * PORT.ASST_LIAB * -1 TR_IE_TRNS
            , COALESCE(FTP_OUT.TP_FINAL, DEFAULT_INDEX.IDX_FORMULA) TR_TP_FINAL
            , FXSPOT.FXRATE
            , DAY(CONVERT(DATE, '2016-10-01')) TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY
        FROM PORT
        LEFT JOIN FTP_OUT ON PORT.TXN_ID = FTP_OUT.TXN_ID
        LEFT JOIN FXSPOT ON PORT.CURRENCY = FXSPOT.CURRENCY1
        LEFT JOIN DEFAULT_INDEX ON 1 = 1
    ), STEP2 AS (
        SELECT
              STEP1.*
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_STATUS_FLG TXN_STATUS_FLG_PRE
            , CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN '0' WHEN FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD IS NOT NULL THEN '1' WHEN FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD IS NULL THEN '2' END TXN_STATUS_FLG
            , STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_BAL_MTD, 0) END TR_BAL_MTD
            , STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_BAL_MTD, 0) END / DAY(CONVERT(DATE, RP_DATA_DT)) TR_AVGBAL_MTD
            , STEP1.T_CURBAL_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_BAL_MTD, 0) END TR_CURBAL_MTD
            , STEP1.T_CURBAL_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_BAL_MTD, 0) END / DAY(CONVERT(DATE, RP_DATA_DT)) TR_AVGCURBAL_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TRNS * -1 TR_FC_TRNS
            , STEP1.TR_IE_INT + STEP1.TR_IE_TRNS TR_MARGIN
            , STEP1.T_POINTAMT_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_POINTAMT_MTD, 0) END TR_POINTAMT_MTD
            , STEP1.T_POINTAMT_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_POINTAMT_MTD, 0) END / DAY(CONVERT(DATE, RP_DATA_DT)) TR_AVGPOINTAMT_MTD
            , STEP1.T_RESTBALC_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_RESTBALC_MTD, 0) END TR_RESTBALC_MTD
            , STEP1.T_RESTBALC_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_RESTBALC_MTD, 0) END / DAY(CONVERT(DATE, RP_DATA_DT)) TR_AVGRESTBALC_MTD
            , STEP1.T_UNEARN_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_UNEARN_MTD, 0) END TR_UNEARN_MTD
            , STEP1.T_UNEARN_DOM + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_UNEARN_MTD, 0) END / DAY(CONVERT(DATE, RP_DATA_DT)) TR_AVGUNEARN_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TRNS * -1 + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_FCTRNS_MTD, 0) END TR_FCTRNS_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TP_ADJ1 + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ1_MTD, 0) END TR_IE_TP_ADJ1_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TP_ADJ2 + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ2_MTD, 0) END TR_IE_TP_ADJ2_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TP_ADJ3 + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ3_MTD, 0) END TR_IE_TP_ADJ3_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TP_ADJ4 + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ4_MTD, 0) END TR_IE_TP_ADJ4_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TP_ADJ5 + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ5_MTD, 0) END TR_IE_TP_ADJ5_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TP_ORG + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ORG_MTD, 0) END TR_IE_TP_ORG_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_INT + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IEINT_MTD, 0) END TR_IEINT_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_TRNS + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IETRNS_MTD, 0) END TR_IETRNS_MTD
            , STEP1.TR_IE_INT + STEP1.TR_IE_TRNS + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_MARGIN_MTD, 0) END TR_MARGIN_MTD
            , STEP1.CUR_GRS_RT * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB W_CUR_GRS_RT
            , (STEP1.CUR_GRS_RT * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB) + CASE WHEN TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FTP_MTD_PRE.W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD, 0) END W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD
            , STEP1.TP_ADJ1 * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TP_ADJ1
            , STEP1.TP_ADJ2 * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TP_ADJ2
            , STEP1.TP_ADJ3 * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TP_ADJ3
            , STEP1.TP_ADJ4 * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TP_ADJ4
            , STEP1.TP_ADJ5 * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TP_ADJ5
            , STEP1.TR_FINAL_SPREAD * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD
            , STEP1.TP_FINAL * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TR_TP_FINAL
            , STEP1.TP_ORIGNAL * STEP1.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM * STEP1.ASST_LIAB * -1 W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD P_W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ1_MTD P_W_TP_ADJ1_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ2_MTD P_W_TP_ADJ2_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ3_MTD P_W_TP_ADJ3_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ4_MTD P_W_TP_ADJ4_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ5_MTD P_W_TP_ADJ5_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD_MTD P_W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_TP_FINAL_MTD P_W_TR_TP_FINAL_MTD
            , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL_MTD P_W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL_MTD
        FROM STEP1
        LEFT JOIN FTP_MTD_PRE ON STEP1.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD = FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD
    )
    INSERT INTO R_PBB_FTP_V1225.DBO.FTP_MTD_MC (
          RP_DATA_DT
        , TXN_ID_R_PRODCD
        , TXN_STATUS_FLG
        , TXN_STATUS_PREV
        , ERR_FLG
        , TXN_ID
        , SCURITY_ID
        , PRODUCT_ID
        , AMRT_TYP
        , ASST_LIAB
        , CUR_BK_BAL
        , T_CUR_BK_BAL
        , CUR_GRS_RT
        , CUR_PMT
        , CURRENCY
        , DAY_COUNT
        , FIX_FLT
        , FSTAMRT_DT
        , FST_CPN_DT
        , ISSUE_DT
        , MAT_DT
        , NXT_RSTDT
        , ORG_PAR_BAL
        , ORG_PAR_BL2
        , PAY_DAY
        , PMT_FLG
        , PMT_FREQ
        , PMT_FREQ_M
        , PRV_RSTDT
        , RST_FRQ
        , RST_FRQ_M
        , SNK_DAY
        , SNK_FRQ
        , SNK_FRQ_M
        , SNK_P_FLG
        , SNK_PMT
        , SNK_RT
        , TENOR
        , TENOR_M
        , TP_ADJ1_ID
        , TP_ADJ2_ID
        , TP_ADJ3_ID
        , TP_ADJ4_ID
        , TP_ADJ5_ID
        , TP_ID
        , TP_INDEX_ID
        , TRANSPRICE
        , RUN_ID
        , CURRENT_DT
        , TP_ORIGNAL
        , TP_ADJ1
        , TP_ADJ2
        , TP_ADJ3
        , TP_ADJ4
        , TP_ADJ5
        , TP_FINAL
        , DURATION
        , WAL
        , USER_INPUT
        , TP_MODEL
        , TP_CLASS
        , YC_DT
        , START_DT
        , END_DT
        , FXRATE
        , CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
        , T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
        , TR_SPREAD
        , TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , TR_TP_FINAL
        , TR_IE_INT
        , TR_IE_TP_ORG
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ1
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ2
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ3
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ4
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ5
        , TR_IE_TRNS
        , TR_MARGIN
        , TR_FC_TRNS
        , TR_DAYS_MTD
        , TR_BAL_MTD
        , TR_AVGBAL_MTD
        , TR_IEINT_MTD
        , TR_IE_TP_ORG_MTD
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ1_MTD
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ2_MTD
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ3_MTD
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ4_MTD
        , TR_IE_TP_ADJ5_MTD
        , TR_IETRNS_MTD
        , TR_MARGIN_MTD
        , TR_FCTRNS_MTD
        , W_CUR_GRS_RT
        , W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL
        , W_TP_ADJ1
        , W_TP_ADJ2
        , W_TP_ADJ3
        , W_TP_ADJ4
        , W_TP_ADJ5
        , W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , W_TR_TP_FINAL
        , W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD
        , W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL_MTD
        , W_TP_ADJ1_MTD
        , W_TP_ADJ2_MTD
        , W_TP_ADJ3_MTD
        , W_TP_ADJ4_MTD
        , W_TP_ADJ5_MTD
        , W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD_MTD
        , W_TR_TP_FINAL_MTD
        , AVG_CUR_GRS_RT
        , AVG_TR_TP_ORIGNAL
        , AVG_TP_ADJ1
        , AVG_TP_ADJ2
        , AVG_TP_ADJ3
        , AVG_TP_ADJ4
        , AVG_TP_ADJ5
        , AVG_TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , AVG_TR_TP_FINAL
        , G_BANKNO
        , G_CSTCTR
        , G_GLACCTNO
        , G_GLACCTYP
        , G_GLACCTINT
        , T_RTTYP
        , T_PMTTYP
        , T_NIDPMMD
        , T_CAHSSS
        , R_LOBCD
        , R_BRNCHCD
        , R_PRODCD
        , R_TYPCD
        , R_HPTYPCD
        , DSC_G_BANKNO
        , DSC_G_CSTCTR
        , DSC_G_GLACCTNO
        , DSC_G_GLACCTYP
        , DSC_G_GLACCTINT
        , DSC_T_RTTYP
        , DSC_T_PMTTYP
        , DSC_T_NIDPMMD
        , DSC_T_CAHSSS
        , DSC_R_LOBCD
        , DSC_R_BRNCHCD
        , DSC_R_PRODCD
        , DSC_R_TYPCD
        , DSC_R_HPTYPCD
        , R_NAME
        , R_CUSTCODE
        , R_PRODTYP
        , R_INTPLAN
        , R_DEPGRP_NAME
        , R_DEPID
        , R_MISC_IND
        , R_SRCTBL
        , R_RESTIND
        , R_SECNO
        , R_PAIDIND
        , T_UNEARN
        , T_UNEARN_DOM
        , TR_UNEARN_MTD
        , TR_AVGUNEARN_MTD
        , T_CURBAL
        , T_CURBAL_DOM
        , TR_CURBAL_MTD
        , TR_AVGCURBAL_MTD
        , T_POINTAMT
        , T_POINTAMT_DOM
        , TR_POINTAMT_MTD
        , TR_AVGPOINTAMT_MTD
        , T_RESTBALC
        , T_RESTBALC_DOM
        , TR_RESTBALC_MTD
        , TR_AVGRESTBALC_MTD
        , CURR_DT
        , R_PROCESS_DT
    )
    SELECT
          STEP2.RP_DATA_DT
        , STEP2.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD
        , STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG
        , STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG_PRE
        , STEP2.ERR_FLG
        , STEP2.TXN_ID
        , STEP2.SCURITY_ID
        , STEP2.PRODUCT_ID
        , STEP2.AMRT_TYP
        , STEP2.ASST_LIAB
        , STEP2.CUR_BK_BAL
        , STEP2.T_CUR_BK_BAL
        , STEP2.CUR_GRS_RT
        , STEP2.CUR_PMT
        , STEP2.CURRENCY
        , STEP2.DAY_COUNT
        , STEP2.FIX_FLT
        , STEP2.FSTAMRT_DT
        , STEP2.FST_CPN_DT
        , STEP2.ISSUE_DT
        , STEP2.MAT_DT
        , STEP2.NXT_RSTDT
        , STEP2.ORG_PAR_BAL
        , STEP2.ORG_PAR_BL2
        , STEP2.PAY_DAY
        , STEP2.PMT_FLG
        , STEP2.PMT_FREQ
        , STEP2.PMT_FREQ_M
        , STEP2.PRV_RSTDT
        , STEP2.RST_FRQ
        , STEP2.RST_FRQ_M
        , STEP2.SNK_DAY
        , STEP2.SNK_FRQ
        , STEP2.SNK_FRQ_M
        , STEP2.SNK_P_FLG
        , STEP2.SNK_PMT
        , STEP2.SNK_RT
        , STEP2.TENOR
        , STEP2.TENOR_M
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ1_ID
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ2_ID
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ3_ID
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ4_ID
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ5_ID
        , STEP2.TP_ID
        , STEP2.TP_INDEX_ID
        , STEP2.TRANSPRICE
        , STEP2.RUN_ID
        , STEP2.CURRENT_DT
        , STEP2.TP_ORIGNAL
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ1
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ2
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ3
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ4
        , STEP2.TP_ADJ5
        , STEP2.TP_FINAL
        , STEP2.DURATION
        , STEP2.WAL
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.USER_INPUT = '' THEN NULL ELSE STEP2.USER_INPUT END USER_INPUT
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TP_MODEL = '' THEN NULL ELSE STEP2.TP_MODEL END TP_MODEL
        , STEP2.TP_CLASS
        , STEP2.YC_DT
        , STEP2.START_DT
        , STEP2.END_DT
        , STEP2.FXRATE
        , STEP2.CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
        , STEP2.T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
        , STEP2.TR_SPREAD
        , STEP2.TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , STEP2.TR_TP_FINAL
        , STEP2.TR_IE_INT
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ORG
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ1
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ2
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ3
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ4
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ5
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TRNS
        , STEP2.TR_MARGIN
        , STEP2.TR_FC_TRNS
        , STEP2.TR_DAYS_MTD_TODAY
        , STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_AVGBAL_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IEINT_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ORG_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ1_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ2_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ3_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ4_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IE_TP_ADJ5_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_IETRNS_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_MARGIN_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_FCTRNS_MTD
        , STEP2.W_CUR_GRS_RT
        , STEP2.W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ1
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ2
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ3
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ4
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ5
        , STEP2.W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , STEP2.W_TR_TP_FINAL
        , STEP2.W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL_MTD END W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ1 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ1_MTD END W_TP_ADJ1_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ2 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ2_MTD END W_TP_ADJ2_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ3 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ3_MTD END W_TP_ADJ3_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ4 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ4_MTD END W_TP_ADJ4_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TP_ADJ5 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ5_MTD END W_TP_ADJ5_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD_MTD END W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD_MTD
        , STEP2.W_TR_TP_FINAL + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TR_TP_FINAL_MTD END W_TR_TP_FINAL_MTD
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_CUR_GRS_RT
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TR_TP_ORIGNAL
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TP_ADJ1 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ1_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TP_ADJ1
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TP_ADJ2 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ2_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TP_ADJ2
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TP_ADJ3 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ3_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TP_ADJ3
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TP_ADJ4 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ4_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TP_ADJ4
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TP_ADJ5 + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TP_ADJ5_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TP_ADJ5
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , CASE WHEN STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (STEP2.W_TR_TP_FINAL + CASE WHEN STEP2.TXN_STATUS_FLG = 0 THEN 0 ELSE STEP2.P_W_TR_TP_FINAL_MTD END) / STEP2.TR_BAL_MTD END AVG_TR_TP_FINAL
        , STEP2.G_BANKNO
        , STEP2.G_CSTCTR
        , STEP2.G_GLACCTNO
        , STEP2.G_GLACCTYP
        , STEP2.G_GLACCTINT
        , STEP2.T_RTTYP
        , STEP2.T_PMTTYP
        , STEP2.T_NIDPMMD
        , STEP2.T_CAHSSS
        , STEP2.R_LOBCD
        , STEP2.R_BRNCHCD
        , STEP2.R_PRODCD
        , STEP2.R_TYPCD
        , STEP2.R_HPTYPCD
        , D1.DESCRIPTION DSC_G_BANKNO
        , D2.DESCRIPTION DSC_G_CSTCTR
        , D3.DESCRIPTION DSC_G_GLACCTNO
        , D4.DESCRIPTION DSC_G_GLACCTYP
        , D5.DESCRIPTION DSC_G_GLACCTINT
        , D6.DESCRIPTION DSC_T_RTTYP
        , D7.DESCRIPTION DSC_T_PMTTYP
        , D8.DESCRIPTION DSC_T_NIDPMMD
        , D9.DESCRIPTION DSC_T_CAHSSS
        , D10.DESCRIPTION DSC_R_LOBCD
        , D11.DESCRIPTION DSC_R_BRNCHCD
        , D12.DESCRIPTION DSC_R_PRODCD
        , D13.DESCRIPTION DSC_R_TYPCD
        , D14.DESCRIPTION DSC_R_HPTYPCD
        , STEP2.R_NAME
        , STEP2.R_CUSTCODE
        , STEP2.R_PRODTYP
        , STEP2.R_INTPLAN
        , STEP2.R_DEPGRP_NAME
        , STEP2.R_DEPID
        , STEP2.R_MISC_IND
        , STEP2.R_SRCTBL
        , STEP2.R_RESTIND
        , STEP2.R_SECNO
        , STEP2.R_PAIDIND
        , STEP2.T_UNEARN
        , STEP2.T_UNEARN_DOM
        , STEP2.TR_UNEARN_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_AVGUNEARN_MTD
        , STEP2.T_CURBAL
        , STEP2.T_CURBAL_DOM
        , STEP2.TR_CURBAL_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_AVGCURBAL_MTD
        , STEP2.T_POINTAMT
        , STEP2.T_POINTAMT_DOM
        , STEP2.TR_POINTAMT_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_AVGPOINTAMT_MTD
        , STEP2.T_RESTBALC
        , STEP2.T_RESTBALC_DOM
        , STEP2.TR_RESTBALC_MTD
        , STEP2.TR_AVGRESTBALC_MTD
        , RP_DATA_DT CURR_DT
        , CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) R_PROCESS_DT
    FROM STEP2
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D1 ON D1.FIELDNAME = 'G_BANKNO' AND STEP2.G_BANKNO = D1.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D2 ON D2.FIELDNAME = 'G_CSTCTR' AND STEP2.G_CSTCTR = D2.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D3 ON D3.FIELDNAME = 'G_GLACCTNO' AND STEP2.G_GLACCTNO = D3.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D4 ON D4.FIELDNAME = 'G_GLACCTYP' AND STEP2.G_GLACCTYP = D4.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D5 ON D5.FIELDNAME = 'G_GLACCTINT' AND STEP2.G_GLACCTINT = D5.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D6 ON D6.FIELDNAME = 'T_RTTYP' AND STEP2.T_RTTYP = D6.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D7 ON D7.FIELDNAME = 'T_PMTTYP' AND STEP2.T_PMTTYP = D7.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D8 ON D8.FIELDNAME = 'T_NIDPMMD' AND STEP2.T_NIDPMMD = D8.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D9 ON D9.FIELDNAME = 'T_CAHSSS' AND STEP2.T_CAHSSS = D9.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D10 ON D10.FIELDNAME = 'R_LOBCD' AND STEP2.R_LOBCD = D10.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D11 ON D11.FIELDNAME = 'R_BRNCHCD' AND STEP2.R_BRNCHCD = D11.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D12 ON D12.FIELDNAME = 'R_PRODCD' AND STEP2.R_PRODCD = D12.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D13 ON D13.FIELDNAME = 'R_TYPCD' AND STEP2.R_TYPCD = D13.CD
    LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D14 ON D14.FIELDNAME = 'R_HPTYPCD' AND STEP2.R_HPTYPCD = D14.CD
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          '2016-10-01' RP_DATA_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD
        , '3' TXN_STATUS_FLG
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_STATUS_FLG
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.ERR_FLG
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.SCURITY_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.PRODUCT_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AMRT_TYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.ASST_LIAB
        , 0 CUR_BK_BAL
        , 0 T_CUR_BK_BAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.CUR_GRS_RT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.CUR_PMT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.CURRENCY
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DAY_COUNT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.FIX_FLT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.FSTAMRT_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.FST_CPN_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.ISSUE_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.MAT_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.NXT_RSTDT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.ORG_PAR_BAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.ORG_PAR_BL2
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.PAY_DAY
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.PMT_FLG
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.PMT_FREQ
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.PMT_FREQ_M
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.PRV_RSTDT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.RST_FRQ
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.RST_FRQ_M
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.SNK_DAY
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.SNK_FRQ
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.SNK_FRQ_M
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.SNK_P_FLG
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.SNK_PMT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.SNK_RT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TENOR
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TENOR_M
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ1_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ2_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ3_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ4_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ5_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_INDEX_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TRANSPRICE
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.RUN_ID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.CURRENT_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ORIGNAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ1
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ2
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ3
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ4
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_ADJ5
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_FINAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DURATION
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.WAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.USER_INPUT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_MODEL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TP_CLASS
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.YC_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.START_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.END_DT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.FXRATE
        , 0 CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
        , 0 T_CUR_BK_BAL_DOM
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_SPREAD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_TP_FINAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_INT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ORG
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ1
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ2
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ3
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ4
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ5
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TRNS
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_MARGIN
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_FC_TRNS
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_DAYS_MTD + 1 TR_DAYS_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_BAL_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_AVGBAL_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IEINT_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ORG_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ1_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ2_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ3_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ4_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IE_TP_ADJ5_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_IETRNS_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_MARGIN_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_FCTRNS_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_CUR_GRS_RT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ1
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ2
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ3
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ4
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ5
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_TP_FINAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_CUR_GRS_RT_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_TP_ORIGNAL_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ1_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ2_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ3_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ4_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TP_ADJ5_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_FINAL_SPREAD_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.W_TR_TP_FINAL_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_CUR_GRS_RT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TR_TP_ORIGNAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TP_ADJ1
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TP_ADJ2
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TP_ADJ3
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TP_ADJ4
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TP_ADJ5
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TR_FINAL_SPREAD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.AVG_TR_TP_FINAL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.G_BANKNO
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.G_CSTCTR
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.G_GLACCTNO
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.G_GLACCTYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.G_GLACCTINT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.T_RTTYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.T_PMTTYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.T_NIDPMMD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.T_CAHSSS
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_LOBCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_BRNCHCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_PRODCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_TYPCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_HPTYPCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_G_BANKNO
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_G_CSTCTR
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_G_GLACCTNO
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_G_GLACCTYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_G_GLACCTINT
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_T_RTTYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_T_PMTTYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_T_NIDPMMD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_T_CAHSSS
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_R_LOBCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_R_BRNCHCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_R_PRODCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_R_TYPCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.DSC_R_HPTYPCD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_NAME
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_CUSTCODE
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_PRODTYP
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_INTPLAN
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_DEPGRP_NAME
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_DEPID
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_MISC_IND
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_SRCTBL
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_RESTIND
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_SECNO
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.R_PAIDIND
        , 0 T_UNEARN
        , 0 T_UNEARN_DOM
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_UNEARN_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_AVGUNEARN_MTD
        , 0 T_CURBAL
        , 0 T_CURBAL_DOM
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_CURBAL_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_AVGCURBAL_MTD
        , 0 T_POINTAMT
        , 0 T_POINTAMT_DOM
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_POINTAMT_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_AVGPOINTAMT_MTD
        , 0 T_RESTBALC
        , 0 T_RESTBALC_DOM
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_RESTBALC_MTD
        , FTP_MTD_PRE.TR_AVGRESTBALC_MTD
        , '2016-10-01' CURR_DT
        , CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) R_PROCESS_DT
    FROM FTP_MTD_PRE
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PORT WHERE FTP_MTD_PRE.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD = PORT.TXN_ID_R_PRODCD)
```

Comment: can you share execution plan here

Comment: Spool not necessarily implies bad thing,even if it is 30%.you hv not mention the actual problem, like if it is slow or very slow etc.sorry to say this,but your  query is very very long with lot of calculation.Wonder what you are doing when " those tables populate" or your database design.

Comment: @KumarHarsh, understand that SPOOL not necessarily a bad thing. Just wondering why it shows up between INSERT and UNION. Can understand if the SPOOL is shown before UNION process, cause there got a lot of JOIN all that. But after that is just INSERT, don't understand why SQL Server put a SPOOL here.
And yes, there is quite a lot of calculations, that's what users want. Still working on tuning the query.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, sure. but need others to help to download the generated plan from server. Will upload to here once I get the file.

Comment: @KumarHarsh, the reason I am look into this is because this query takes about 1 hour to finish (TBL2, 3, 5 all have around 13 million records). And about 70% at INSERT and 25% at SPOOL. So I would like to take out this SPOOL if it's not necessary.

Comment: not very expert in evaluating such large plan.Say that spool is not in our hand.if resultset return is large then execution plan may decide to store in spool.There are lot of table scan.What should be the actual no. of rows return from your query.In nutshell,you have to optimize your query.

Comment: I went through your query once agian.I am sure not even a single CTE solve the purpose.Use all the table directly.Performance won't degrade further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soool is copy of data in temp db .

Query have cte  used to create new cte so execution logic is getting complicated to solve the problem sql server need to create interim result set the same is visible in query plan as spool.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181032(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: understand that. But then shouldn't it appear somewhere before UNION? Cause there is the place I do all the JOIN and calculations. Why it appears after the result is JOINed?

Comment: you can share execution plan ....  as mention it could be any place where ever sql server need some interim data to be stored for further and in union sql server need to remove duplication of data for that it need to short data and compare result sets.. ...

Comment: @ sandeep rawat. just uploaded the Execution Plan.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO , there is no point in CTE where there is no filter or calculation
for example LK_ALL,you can directly use #DBNAME#.DBO.#TBL4# where req. it may or may not improve performance,but at least it reduce number of lines.

It is really tough to debug, whole query.

but see here instead of so many left join(BTW,if you can use inner join)
you can rewrite your query like this,

```
FROM STEP2
Inner/LEFT JOIN LK_ALL D1 ON (STEP2.G_BANKNO = D1.CD AND D1.FIELDNAME = 'G_BANKNO') 
or (D2.FIELDNAME = 'G_CSTCTR' AND STEP2.G_CSTCTR = D2.CD       )
or (D3.FIELDNAME = 'G_GLACCTNO' AND STEP2.G_GLACCTNO = D3.CD   )
or (D4.FIELDNAME = 'G_GLACCTYP' AND STEP2.G_GLACCTYP = D4.CD   )
or (D5.FIELDNAME = 'G_GLACCTINT' AND STEP2.G_GLACCTINT = D5.CD )
or (D6.FIELDNAME = 'T_RTTYP' AND STEP2.T_RTTYP = D6.CD         )
or (D7.FIELDNAME = 'T_PMTTYP' AND STEP2.T_PMTTYP = D7.CD       )
or (D8.FIELDNAME = 'T_NIDPMMD' AND STEP2.T_NIDPMMD = D8.CD     )
or (D9.FIELDNAME = 'T_CAHSSS' AND STEP2.T_CAHSSS = D9.CD       )
or ( D10.FIELDNAME = 'R_LOBCD' AND STEP2.R_LOBCD = D10.CD      )
or ( D11.FIELDNAME = 'R_BRNCHCD' AND STEP2.R_BRNCHCD = D11.CD  )
or ( D12.FIELDNAME = 'R_PRODCD' AND STEP2.R_PRODCD = D12.CD    )
or ( D13.FIELDNAME = 'R_TYPCD' AND STEP2.R_TYPCD = D13.CD      )
or ( D14.FIELDNAME = 'R_HPTYPCD' AND STEP2.R_HPTYPCD = D14.CD  )
```

I hope those hard coded parameter are dynamic in real life
Also you can do like,

declare @From date= dateadd(day,-1,'2016-10-01')

declare @To int= DAY(DATEADD(D, 1, CONVERT(DATE, RP_DATA_DT)))

for millions of records temp table is better than CTE.

Also you can comment part of query to see the performance.

Comment: @ KumarHarsh Thanks for the advise. Will try to use Temp Table instead CTE to see if can speed up the query.

And yes, all those hard coded date and string are indeed variable. Just output as fixed value when generated.

Comment: No, CTE in general do not store in memory.it is Execution plan that decide whether it should store part of data in spool.